# RecyclerView with 2 columns. Not center vertically

Tags: android

Here my fragment set recyclerView:

```
sortRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager rvLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
sortRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManager);
```

Here fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/place_holder_color">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/sortRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here my item layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/preview_image_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/preview_image_height"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFavorite"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_like_inactive"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/offer_rounded_corner_bottom_bg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageViewPhoto">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewDownload"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/bottomContainer"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bottomContainer" />              

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>   

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here result with 2 columns:

[image: rv]

As you can see the items of RecyclerView is align by left side. But I need to center it vertically.

Here result with one column (again not align on center)

[image: one]

Comment: can u explain more about it

Comment: Could you put your item layout?

Comment: I update my post

Comment: Set your ConstraintLayout's width and height MatchParent . Or wrap it inside a Layout with center allign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/place_holder_color">

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/sortRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

change your custom layout like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFavorite"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, I set "android:layout_width="match_parent" on "ConstraintLayout" in  in item layout

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
item_layout.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Add `SpanSizeLookup` to your `GridlayoutManager` for last item to center.

```
gridlayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                @Override
                public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                    if (position == imageUrls.size - 1) {
                        return 2; // the item in position now takes up 4 spans
                    }
                    return 1;
                }
            });
        }
```

**Note:** Make your item layout's root view width to `match_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

You create class & extend this RecyclerView.ItemDecoration  In constructor pass number of items in row & space between items like this
 public class SpaceItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

```
private int space;
private int columnSpan;
private int topSpace;

public SpaceItemDecoration(int space, int columnSpan,int topSpace) {
    this.space = space;
    this.columnSpan = columnSpan;
    this.topSpace = topSpace;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
    int rightPosition = position - columnSpan;
    parent.getLayoutManager();

    // Left
    if(position % columnSpan == 0){
        outRect.right = space;
    }
    // Right
    else if(rightPosition % columnSpan != 0){
        outRect.left = space;
    }       

    outRect.top = topSpace;
    outRect.bottom = topSpace;
}
```

}